# ssrs report developement

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have two levels in report issuelevel1 and issue level2 based on levels i need to page break,i did that but i am getting only issue level1 on both the pages what to do to get issue level2 on second page

Comment: share your report design, what the output looks like now and what you want it to look like. Also, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.